# Extending java.base in a project built with Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, java-module

Maven 3.9.0 invalid flag `--patch-module` is what I get when I run `mvn clean compile` on my project that extends `java.lang` package. When I run `javac --patch-module java.base=src <path-to-source>` all is good.

The reason is - Maven uses `com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool` which when parsing `<compilerArgs>` is using only the `BASIC` Option group and `--patch-module` is in the `FILEMANAGER` group. This raises an `illegal flag` exception during `mvn clean compile`.

Does anyone know how I can get it to work with Maven? I'd prefer not to make my CI pipeline using `javac` command line tool.

Project structure is like:
src -> main -> java -> java.lang ->

`pom.xml` looks like:

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.sdk}</source>
                    <target>${java.source.sdk}</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--patch-module java.base=src</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Maven version:

```
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.0/libexec
Java version: 18, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Users/<username>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-18/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_RS, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.6.2", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

Used JDK 19 -> same result. Used Maven 3.10.1 -> same result.

Full error is:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project commons-bootstrap: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid flag: --patch-module java.base=src -> [Help 1]`

Exception stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error: invalid flag: --patch-module java.base=src
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.reportDiag (Arguments.java:889)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.doProcessArgs (Arguments.java:395)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.processArgs (Arguments.java:347)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.init (Arguments.java:246)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1209)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:198)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:577)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `extending java.lang` and why do you want tp do that? Have you tried splitting `<arg>--patch-module java.base=src</arg>` into `<arg>--patch-module</arg><arg>java.base=src</arg>`?

Comment: Because one of my classes is using the `package private` constructor of the String.class to avoid copying the char[] array. It's something I'm looking to remove as the process of migration from JDK 1.8 to JDK 19.

Until then to get back to `--patch-module` - yes I tried splitting it up and it doesn't work. As I said `--patch-module` option is not in a BASIC group of Options for JavacTool argument options.

Comment: Why do you need to the package private constructor instead of just using a reference to the original string? Modifying the `java.base` module for things like that is...a very bad idea

Comment: Try with `fork` options of m-compiler-p https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#fork

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski did that - it still uses JavacTool just as a separate process from the main one.

Comment: @dan1st 'cause I want to avoid double allocation of the humongous objects on the heap when converting `char[]` to `String` - and I can't find a `String` constructor that allows me to pass `char[]` and reuse it - all of them underneath do the `copy` to a newly allocated array.

Comment: Then you should probably think about implementing another way (e.g. using `StringBuilder`) instead of relying on unsupported and inaccessible features that require patching the java.base module. Aside from that, the [package private constructor using a `char[]`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/d6716d2e5471ee794df8833430dd3171b565f78e/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L4503) **still copies all the data** /allocates a new object with it because `String` uses a `byte[]`.

Comment: Also, creating strings with custom arrays compromises JDK safeguards/guarantees resulting in bugs that are very hard to debug.

Comment: It is true since JDK 9 - prior to it Java used char[] (can't copy source code in the comment it clutters the response). With regards to the "cleverness" of the idea - I agree but it's another topic - StringBuilder creates a copy of a String thus duplicating amount of heap usage.

Comment: You don't want to copy the array, therefore you use a method that is much more expensive. Doesn't sound like a great idea to me.

Comment: Want to thank @dan1st for challenging the idea - made me dig down into `String` changes since JDK 1.7 and actually ended up refactoring the piece requiring that private constructor. Since they moved to `byte[]` I managed to refactor dependent methods to provide byte[] in the first place and remove that `char[]` altogether from the middle.

Comment: Not sure if the question should remain open - `Javac API` still does not allow for `--patch-module` compiler option to be used through Maven 3?

Comment: Next options to try: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#forceJavacCompilerUse

Comment: You should set `<maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>` while building with JDK19 also remove `package private constructor of the String.class to avoid copying the char[] array.`... there is a reason why a constructor of a class is package private... means do not use it... If everything build ... lift the version to 19...

Comment: I hope you refactored it in a way that doesn't require calling private or package-private members. Because you should _really_ not do that unless you want your program to completely break beyond all repair.

Comment: Code served its purpose for the past 8 years in production ... time to move on. Basically that code converted `byte[]` to `char[]` and it avoided making another copy of a `char[]` by using normal constructor. That's why it used `package private String(char[], boolean)`. Now since String support `byte[]` constructor I just let the `String(byte[], int, int, Charset)` constructor makes it's own `char[]` - memory footprint remains the same, no `package private` and thus moved the entire library into normal JAR packaging.

Comment: Where does the `byte[]` array come from? In case of an external source, note that when you read a file into a `String` via [`Files.readString(path［,charset］)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)) there might be even less copying. In either case, it’s a good idea to use the builtin charset conversion, as it is highly optimized (for the commonly used charsets) and may use tricks, ordinary application code can’t do, but without compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

Maven parses the argument as one long argument with embedded whitespace.

This is what it is supposed to look like:

```
<compilerArgs>
    <arg>--patch-module</arg>
    <arg>java.base=src</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

See the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#compilerArgs) for example.